Evaluate $\iint\limits_{S}{{z\ dS}}$ where $S$ is the upper half of a sphere of radius 2
the following question is from this website Example 2.
Evaluate $\iint\limits_{S}{{z\ dS}}$ where $S$ is the upper half of a sphere of radius 2.
My code here is basically from How can I evaluate surface integral in Mathematica?.
I am using 12.0 version of mathematica
Clear[DoubleContourIntegral];
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
   surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> 
        param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}), {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, 
      v2_}}] := 
  Integrate[
   Dot[field /. Thread[changeOfVars], 
    Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];

Clear[a, b, c];
S = {{x, y, z} -> {2 Sin[u] Cos[v], 2 Sin[u] Sin[v], 2 Cos[u]}, {u, 
    0, \[Pi]/2}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}};
F = {0, 0, z};
\[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S

The results will be different from the one the aurhor provided. What's wrong?

$Version (*12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12,2020)*)

Here an alternative way using the given coordinate system spherical coordinates (which confirms @user64494's   result )
vec  = {2 Sin[u] Cos[v], 2 Sin[u] Sin[v], 2 Cos[u]}
{gu, gv} = {D[vec, u], D[vec, v]}
dS = Sqrt[# . #] &[Cross[gu, gv]] // Simplify (* surface area element*)

Integrate[vec[[3]] dS, {u, 0, Pi/2}, {v, -Pi, Pi}]  (* 8Pi *)

addendum
Here I present QP's corrected code, which gives correct result 8Pi
Try
Clear[DoubleContourIntegral];
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
   surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> 
        param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}), {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, 
      v2_}}] := 
  Integrate[( field[[3]] /. Thread[changeOfVars]) Norm[
     Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]] , {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];

Clear[a, b, c];
S = {{x, y, z} -> {2 Sin[u] Cos[v], 2 Sin[u] Sin[v], 2 Cos[u]}, {u, 
    0, \[Pi]/2}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}};
F = {0, 0, z};
\[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S
(* 8Pi *)

Hope it helps!

Why did the original code has field[[3]]? What does this mean?

That is the z-component of integrand field.

Since 13.3 SurfaceIntegrate  is implemented. Unfortunately, there is no UpperSemisphere in Mathematica. To overcome it, Max[z,0] is integrated over the whole sphere:
SurfaceIntegrate[Max[z, 0], {x, y, z} \[Element] Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 2]]


8 \[Pi]

That integral  can also be calculated by the definition, Upper semi-sphere is described by its equation
z[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[4-x^2-y^2]

. Then
Integrate[z[x, y]*Sqrt[1 + D[z[x, y], x]^2 + D[z[x, y], y]^2], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2]]


8*Pi


Can you try 12,0 version when there is no SurfaceIntegrate?

@kile: Did you read "That integral can also be calculated by the definition, ..." in my answer before having commented? I think the second way works in 12.0.
